# Cardinal of quotient set

Tags: cardinals, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

Consider a finite set $X$ and let's denote by $F$ the set of all maps defined on $X$ with values in  $\mathbb{N}$.

1. How to prove that $F$ is countable.

Let $\pi_1, \pi_2 \in F$. We define the binary relation $\mathcal{R}$ as follows $\pi_1 \mathcal{R} \pi_2$ if $\forall i,j \in X, \pi_1(i) \leq \pi_1(j)  \Leftrightarrow  \pi_2(i) \leq \pi_2(j)$.

In other words, both functions are "ordering" the elements of $X$ in the same way.
Obviously it's an equivalence relation.

2.How to compute the cardinal of the quotient set $F/ \mathcal{R}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? We can help you better once we know where you're coming from and what exactly you're struggling with. Also, try to avoid asking questions that look like you want us to do your homework for you - they tend not to be well received.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If you’ve already seen that $\Bbb N^n$ is countable for each positive integer $n$, for (1) you could list $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ and find a bijection between $F$ and $\Bbb N^n$. For (2), observe that each $f\in F$ defines a [*preorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) (or *quasiorder*) on $X$. There’s a connection between these preorders and the relation $\mathcal{R}$.